How to translate reading-time without adding node_modules to git?
In locale on my pc I translate the reading-time package to my language and it is in the node_module folder, but I read that I should not add node_modules to a github repository.
Actually the node module is not on git, but I don't get the translation of the reading-time on my website online.
Is there a way to get the translation of the reading time without adding node_modules to git, please?
